# PHP SoapClient: Action mismatch

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I am trying to use the PHP SoapClient extension to communicate with an external SOAP server.

This is my code:

```
$this->_client = new SoapClient(SOAP_TAGGING_URL, array(
    'trace' => 1, 
    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_2, 
    'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE, 
    'exceptions' => true, 
    'uri' => SOAP_URI, 
)); 
try { 
    $actionHdr = array(); 
    $actionHdr[] = new SoapHeader(SOAP_TAGGING_URL, 'Action', 'GetMessagesByTagsByGroup'); 
    $this->_client->__setSoapHeaders($actionHdr);
    $info = $this->_client->GetMessagesByTagsByGroup( 
        new SoapParam($this->params['mPID'], 'ParentMessageID'), 
        new SoapParam($gid, 'GroupId'), 
        new SoapParam(REQUEST_TOKEN, 'RequestToken'), 
        new SoapParam(ACCESS_TOKEN, 'AccessToken'), 
        new SoapParam(ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET, 'AccessTokenSecret') 
    );  
} catch (SoapFault $fault) { 
    print("\n<br/>SOAP server returned the following ERROR: ".$fault->faultcode."-".$fault->faultstring); 
}

echo "\n<br/>SOAP request: ". htmlentities($this->_client->__getLastRequest());
echo "\n<br/>SOAP response: ". htmlentities($this->_client->__getLastResponse());
```

This is the response I get (formatting added):

```
    SOAP server returned the following ERROR: s:Sender-The SOAP action specified on the message, '', does not match the HTTP SOAP Action,     'http://tempuri.org/ITagging/GetMessagesByTagsByGroup'. 
SOAP request: 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:ns2="https://mywebserver.com/myWSDL.svc/ws?wsdl">
    <env:Header>
        <ns2:Action>GetMessagesByTagsByGroup</ns2:Action>
    </env:Header>
    <env:Body>
        <ns1:GetMessagesByTagsByGroup/>
            <GroupId>2178</GroupId>
            <RequestToken>odwedwo09i0jACqbbjsw6KnlCA=</RequestToken>        
            <AccessToken>OlVbHurPJrNrEFR54Y0hV9kI/TZs=</AccessToken>
            <AccessTokenSecret>js1kerfe453FLuaXpL 892DY o=</AccessTokenSecret>
    </env:Body>
</env:Envelope> 
SOAP response: 
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
<s:Header>
    <a:Action s:mustUnderstand="1">http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing/fault</a:Action>    
</s:Header>
    <s:Body>
        <s:Fault>
            <s:Code>
                <s:Value>s:Sender</s:Value>
                <s:Subcode>
                    <s:Value>a:ActionMismatch</s:Value>
                </s:Subcode>
            </s:Code>
            <s:Reason>
                <s:Text xml:lang="en-US">The SOAP action specified on the message, '', does not match the HTTP SOAP Action, 'http://tempuri.org/ITagging/GetMessagesByTagsByGroup'. </s:Text>
            </s:Reason>
            <s:Detail>
                <a:ProblemHeaderQName>a:Action</a:ProblemHeaderQName>
            </s:Detail>
        </s:Fault>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

I thought I added the 'Action' parameter in the header, but clearly that is not the place to put it. Or am I doing something else wrong?

Unfortunately I cannot try NuSoap because I have no control over the server.

Thank you,

gm

Comment: have you tried to use zend soap?

Answer (score 2):

It means meant that not only you must specify the HTTP header SOAPAction: "http://www.bla.com:MyAction"

but you need to specify also in the SOAP Envelope the header:
Check these links for some ref:
[SOAP ACTION](http://www.dimuthu.org/blog/2008/11/25/the-use-of-soap-action-with-wsfphp/)

Comment: I'm not sure how the WSClient class differs from the SoapClient class. I have set the action in the header, but it seems to be ignored.

Answer (score 1):

You're passing it as SoapHeader, but actually it is HTTP header.

The way I found to do it is: http://lt.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.dorequest.php by setting $action parameter.

You'll probably need to extend SoapClient class to do it using less lines of code.

Comment: What is the difference between SoapHeader and HTTP header? I extended the SoapClient class to dump the action name before performing __doRequest, and the action is already set there. 
I have tried many ways and options, but I still get the same error.